# Fetch a variable from node_modules

Tags: node.js, express, node-modules, keystonejs

I am trying to fetch a variable from node_modules to my application. I have exported it with module.exports, but when I use `require('path/of/required/file/in/node_modules')` it is showing 'unexpected token import'. I am trying to get the user info from node_modules since there is no official strategy for keystone to fetch the user data.

*My local file*

```
var keystone = require('keystone');
Teaching = keystone.list('teaching');
UserInfo = require('../../node_modules/keystone/admin/client/App/components/Footer/index.js').footer;
User = keystone.list(keystone.get('user model'));
console.log(User);
exports = module.exports =function(req,res){
    var view = new keystone.View(req,res);   
    var locals = res.locals;

    locals.section = 'teaching';
    locals.data = {
        teachingData : []
    };

    view.on('init',function(next){
        var teaching = Teaching.model.find();
        teaching.exec(function(err,results){
           locals.data.teachingData = results;
           //console.log(locals.data.teachingData);
           next(err);
        });
    });
    view.render('teaching');     
}
```

*Node_module file*

```
import React from 'react';
import { css, StyleSheet } from 'aphrodite/no-important';
import { Container } from '../../elemental';
import theme from '../../../theme';

var Footer = React.createClass({
displayName: 'Footer',
propTypes: {
    appversion: React.PropTypes.string,
    backUrl: React.PropTypes.string,
    brand: React.PropTypes.string,
    user: React.PropTypes.object,
    User: React.PropTypes.object, // eslint-disable-line react/sort-prop-types
    version: React.PropTypes.string,
},
// Render the user
renderUser () {
    const { User, user } = this.props;
    if (!user) return null;
    return (
        <span>
            <span> Signed in as </span>
            <a href={`${Keystone.adminPath}/${User.path}/${user.id}`} tabIndex="-1" className={css(classes.link)}>
                {user.name}
            </a>
            <span>.</span>
        </span>
    );
},


render () {
        const { backUrl, brand, appversion, version } = this.props;

        return (
            <footer className={css(classes.footer)} data-keystone-footer>
                <Container>
                    <a
                        href={backUrl}
                        tabIndex="-1"
                        className={css(classes.link)}
                    >
                        {brand + (appversion ? (' ' + appversion) : '')}
                    </a>
                    <span> powered by </span>
                    <a
                        href=""
                        target="_blank"
                        className={css(classes.link)}
                        tabIndex="-1"
                    >
                        VK
                    </a>
                    <span> version {version}.</span>
                    {this.renderUser()}
                </Container>
            </footer>
        );
       },
     });
/* eslint quote-props: ["error", "as-needed"] */
const linkHoverAndFocus = {
    color: theme.color.gray60,
    outline: 'none',
};
const classes = StyleSheet.create({
    footer: {
        boxShadow: '0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)',
        color: theme.color.gray40,
        fontSize: theme.font.size.small,
        paddingBottom: 30,
        paddingTop: 40,
        textAlign: 'center',
    },
    link: {
        color: theme.color.gray60,

        ':hover': linkHoverAndFocus,
        ':focus': linkHoverAndFocus,
    },
});

exports.footer = Footer.renderUser();
```

Answer (score 1):

1) The "Unexpected token import" error is probably occuring because the current JavaScript environment does not support the `import` statement; the code you are trying to import from the Keystone node module is transpiled before it gets used normally. When Keystone uses that component, it's not an issue. But if you're importing a React component into a non-React file, you're bound to have problems. Which leads to my next question:

2) `UserInfo` isn't used in your code at all. You can't just use Keystone's React component for showing user information, unless you are working in a React environment (which it does not look like you are.) What is your use case for using this component?

Comment: Since there is no way to implement co-admin part in KeystoneJS(where I can expose few of the admin dashboard models) , I want to fetch user info and provide a case like if( userName == "so and so" ){Show this model}else{Hide the model}

Comment: Can I fetch the user.name from middleware and export it to my models?